Travelling to the US with an ESTA and planning to enter Canada on a working holiday visa after that
I will be flying to US on an ESTA next week. I'm planning to be in the USA for 6 weeks, and since I have been granted a working holiday visa by the Canadian government, I want to fly to Canada after my time in the USA (6 weeks).
Since I only have a one-way ticket (Paris-New York) and a ticket New York-Montreal, will I have any issues at the border when entering the USA?
Will the officer understand my purpose of starting my work and holiday visa in Canada after my time in the USA? I have proof of flight ticket (New York-Montreal) + proof of Canadian working holiday visa (which runs for a year).
Thank you in advance!

I had a similar arrangement and had no issues when entering the USA.  I did have questions asked at the departure airport before flying to the US, however.
We had ESTA and one-way flight to the US, then a flight into Mexico where we were moving to live.  The CBP officer when arriving in LAX had no issues with the arrangement.  We just said we were moving to Mexico and were traveling there in a few days.
At our departure airport at airline check-in we had to prove we had all the necessary documents etc. because ESTA required an onward ticket.  But once we showed the flight to Mexico and told them we were moving there, they had no further questions

The eligibility requirements for entering the US under the Visa Waiver Program (ie, ESTA) are listed on the US CBP website.
The two requirements on this page that are relevant to your questions are these :

Have a return or onward ticket
Travel does not terminate in contiguous territory or adjacent islands unless the traveler is a resident of one of those areas

You do have a "return or onward ticket" (to Canada), so you meet that requirement.
Your ticket IS to a "contiguous territory" (Canada), which would normally NOT be sufficient for entry to the US under the Visa Waiver Program. However as you can see from this page, there is an exception where "the traveler is a resident of one of those areas".
Now of course you're not currently a resident of Canada, but once you arrive you will be a temporary resident, which will be sufficient for this condition to apply.
The whole point of the "contiguous territory" clause of the VWP is to avoid people doing "visa runs" to Canada/Mexico/etc - which obviously isn't what you are doing.
